# iOS Replace Keyboard with UIPickerView then Back to Keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, uipickerview, uikeyboard

I have a textfield in my app in which a user can choose a Group they belong to, along with several other fields.  When they get to the Group TextField, it pops up a UIPickerView that has several choices that have already been created, along with an option to "Create New Group". When that option is chosen, I want the UIPickerView to go away, and have the keyboard pop back up so they can type again.  I can get the picker view to appear and to go away, but can't get the keyboard back.  Here is code so far.

```
-(void)addPickerView{

     __block NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    PFQuery *rejectedNumber = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Group"];
    [rejectedNumber orderByAscending:@"GroupName"];
    [rejectedNumber findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {



        if (!objects) {
            // Did not find any UserStats for the current user

            NSLog(@"NotFound");
        } else {
            pickerArray = objects;
            [myPickerView reloadAllComponents];

        }
    }];

     //pickerArray = GoGo;
    self.theView.signUpView.additionalField.delegate = self;
    [self.theView.signUpView.additionalField setPlaceholder:@"Choose Group"];
    myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];
    myPickerView.dataSource = self;
    myPickerView.delegate = self;
    myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                   target:self action:@selector(finishIt)];
    UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:
                          CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-
                                     self.theView.signUpView.additionalField.frame.size.height-50, 320, 50)];
    [toolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
    NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             doneButton, nil];
    [toolBar setItems:toolbarItems];
    self.theView.signUpView.additionalField.inputView = myPickerView;
    self.theView.signUpView.additionalField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;

}
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [pickerArray count] + 1;
}

#pragma mark- Picker View Delegate

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:
(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    if (row == 0)
        [self.theView.signUpView.additionalField.inputView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.theView.signUpView.additionalField becomeFirstResponder];

    }
    else {

    [self.theView.signUpView.additionalField setText:self.theGroup];
    }
}
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *groupName  = @"Create New Group";
    if (row != 0)
    {
        PFObject *object = pickerArray[row - 1]; // -1 to handle the array index
        self.theGroup    = object[@"GroupName"];
        groupName        = object[@"GroupName"];
    }
    return groupName;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing i noticed is, you missed a braces here after if condition:

```
if (row == 0)
    [self.theView.signUpView.additionalField.inputView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.theView.signUpView.additionalField becomeFirstResponder];

}
```

Instead use this:

```
if (row == 0) {
    [self.theView.signUpView.additionalField resignFirstResponder];
    self.theView.signUpView.additionalField.inputView = nil;
    [self.theView.signUpView.additionalField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works.  The { was there in my code, I just accidentally deleted it from when I posted earlier.  How can I change it so that the PickerView starts out highlighted on a blank row?  Right now the first row is Create New Group and you have to navigate away and then back again to select it.  Thoughts?